# Python and Termlib: How do I delete the line after tn.write('wrongstring')?

Tags: python, terminal

I would like to simulate a user interaction with a Remote terminal
The short-cut to delete the line from a terminal emulator is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

Assume that a telnet session is up:

```
HOST='1.1.1.1'
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.write('wrongstring')
```

Now I need to delete this line. How do I do that? How do I send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to the terminal via tn.write?

Edit: This did the trick

```
tn.write('\x15')
```

Not sure why the ASCII sequence suggested below did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're providing input to a remote shell interpreter, sending <kbd>controlU</kbd> will not help.

If you are writing to a terminal which accepts "ANSI escapes", it probably knows how to erase the current line.  Referring to [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html):

```
CSI Ps K  Erase in Line (EL).
            Ps = 0  -> Erase to Right (default).
            Ps = 1  -> Erase to Left.
            Ps = 2  -> Erase All.
```

you could erase the whole line by writing `"\033[2K"`.  That will not move the cursor.  You could also move the cursor to the left margin (on many terminals)

```
CSI Ps G  Cursor Character Absolute  [column] (default = [row,1]) (CHA).
```

by writing `"\033[G"`.  Finally, if you had to remove the *previous* line, you could move the cursor up with the `CPL` or `VPA` control sequence (which are less widely implemented).